# Do my games in the GoKGS get deleted after some time?

Tags: go, kgs

At this page (https://www.gokgs.com/help/tilde.html) I read:

> Your whole list of games (i.e. all those played in the last 180 days) ...

This kind of suggests that "my whole list of games" = "all those played in the last 180 days", which suggests that in my list there are never games older than 180 days, which suggests that they get deleted?

Comment: This seems like the kind of question that would be better addressed to the administrators of that website. We don't have any way of knowing their deletion policy except what the website says.

Comment: Thanks @murgatroid99, I planned to ask them - send them link to this page. In any case I think it is better that it is asked here publicly, as the answer will be published here as well for anyone who might have the same question in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mentioned list of games is the list that is displayed in your profile. It only displays games from the last 180 days and only the games in the last 180 days are considered for the rank graph. You can review these games directly (right click on a game in the list --> *Load in ...* or *Load in (P)*).

All games (even these which are older than 180 days) are listed in the [archive](http://www.gokgs.com/archives.jsp). There you can access all games which are not private. Unlike the games which not older than 180 days you must download them first to review them. I just don't know if *private* games are just not accessible in the archive but accessible on demand or are even deleted.

Comment: Thanks Ching Chong. *"The mentioned list of games is the list that is displayed in your profile"* - how do you know that it refers to the profile and not to the archive? They just meantion "Your whole list of games", and the word "whole" is confusing. It suggests there are no more games apart from those. So is it just a bad wording?

Comment: You can look at other players' profiles and archive pages for games older than 180 days. You will observe that you won't find the older games in the profile but in the archive. Therefore: Yes, it's just bad wording.